# JLayeredPane with gridlayout?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, jlayeredpane

Is there a way for me to add buttons to the right side of my JLayeredPane? The layered pane contains a JPanel which represents a chess board and on top of this board I have JLabels representing chess pieces. I want basically another panel attached to the right side of the board which contains player information and buttons allowing for rematches/etc. What would be the best way to go about adding this panel?

Here is a snippet of my code. The part which sets up the board panel inside the layeredpane:

```
private void setupBoard() {
    paneX = new JLayeredPane();
    getContentPane().add(paneX);
    paneX.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

    boardX = new JPanel(); 
    paneX.add(boardX, JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);
    boardX.setLayout(new GridLayout(8,8));
    boardX.setBounds(0,0,500,500);
    chessBoard.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
}
```

Then, I go on to add the jlabels to each component on the panel. I want to add another big panel attached to the right side of the board like I mentioned earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't quite see why you would use a `JLayeredPane` for this, but that's just me.

Set the `Layout` for the main container to `BorderLayout`.  Add the `boardX` to the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position of the main container.

Add the player information panel to the `BorderLayout.EAST` position of the main container.

Setting the `bounds` of the `boardX` is not really going to have any effect, as the parent container will want to use the panels preferred/minimum/maximum size (based on whatever layout manager you might use) to determine the best size to make it, which based on your code, would probably be 500x500 anyway...

Comment: what would you suggest instead of jlayeredpane?

Comment: Explain to me why you're using a `JLayeredPane`?  What are you adding to it?

Comment: I'm new to java swing so I was guessing the layeredpane would allow me to layer the board and then the labels on the board. But now that I think about it the labels are on the board, not the layeredpane. What would be the best alternative to layeredpane?

Comment: It would, until you added a layout manager to it ;).  Personally, I would make each "cell" on the board something like a `JPanel`, setting it's layout to `BorderLayout` and then add/remove components directory to/from these cells.  That way the layering is taken care for you.  This would require you to, obviously, know which panel belonged to which cell though... ;)